# Examples of statements that are equi-consistent and indeterminate of ZFC + [V=L]?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

1- What are examples of statements that are indeterminate from $\sf ZFC + [V=L]$ that are comparable to the situation of $\sf CH$ with regards to $\sf ZFC$. I mean I need a statement $\psi$ such that $\sf ZFC + [V=L]$ is equi-consistent with the addition of $\psi$ or $\neg \psi$ to it. That is, a statement that both itself an its negation doesn't increase the consistency strength of $\sf ZFC +[V=L]$ when added to it. Are there some simple natural statements. In particular, are there some statements regarding cardinal comparisons?

I'll add another related question, that is:

2- if we instead of the simple natural requirement, replace it by $\psi$ meeting the following two conditions:

$\sf (ZFC+[V=L] + \psi) \not \vdash Con(ZFC) \\ \sf (ZFC+[V=L]+  \psi) \not \vdash \neg Con(ZFC)$

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "cardinal comparisons"? V=L implies GCH, so in that sense, cardinal arithmetic is completely determined.

Comment: Also, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11480/on-statements-independent-of-zfc-v-l), though I don't know that any of the examples presented or alluded to are equiconsistent (most certainly are not). One trivial (and probably not considered 'natural') example is the Rosser sentence for ZFC+V=L.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I saw the references you've mentioned, in the first one all of the examples raise consistency strength. About the Rosser sentence which can be seen at this answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/18076/95347), I'd say it is not natural at all and definitely not simple.

Comment: Note we're pretty severely hamstrung in terms of usual methods for producing equiconsistent "natural" examples. Neither forcing nor inner models will work here. Not to mention that V=L has the habit of deciding just about everything.

Comment: What do you mean by "natural"? Same for "simple".

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, these are difficult to characterize, but lets say sentences that do not involve coding of formulas as objects of the theory like what's happening with L itself, this is deemed complex (i.e.; not simple). By natural I mean non-self referential, i.e. sentences that are not understood to refer to themselves, these would be also complex because they'll involve sentence coding, that of themselves. Most large cardinal sentences are natural, also the usual theorems of arithmetic and set theory are.

Comment: Do you simply mean something analogous to the Paris-Harrington theorem, or the Kirby-Paris “Hydra” theorem, for PA? These were widely seen as “natural” examples of results independent of PA. Anyway, I’d have to echo spaceisdarkgreen’s comment about the difficulty of coming up with such an example.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss, yes of course such statements are indeed natural.

Comment: Rosser's sentence qualifies for the related question

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I thought adding it would prove Con($\sf ZFC$) since the resulting theory would prove the unprovability of it in $\sf ZFC $

Comment: @Zuhair It better not imply Con(ZFC) if it’s equiconsistent with ZFC. The Rosser sentence asserts something weaker than its own unprovability.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen but the resulting theory would prove the unprovability of the Rosser sentence from ZFC and so the resulting theory proves Con(ZFC)

Comment: Continuation... Con(ZFC) is equivalent to Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)) so they (ie, ZFC, ZFC+Con(ZFC)) are equiconsistent, yet the latter (ie, ZFC+Con(ZFC)) proves Con(ZFC)

Comment: @Zuhair huh? Con(ZFC) and Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)) are not equivalent. ZFC + Con(ZFC) is strictly higher consistency strength than ZFC.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, if ZFC is consistent, then it cannot prove Con(ZFC), and so $\sf Con(ZFC) \implies Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC))$, the other direction is evident.

Comment: @Zuhair That’s an argument that Con(ZFC) implies Con(ZFC+ $\lnot$Con(ZFC)), which is true.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, technically speaking Con(ZFC) and $\neg$Con(ZFC) both are unprovable in ZFC, so the consistency of ZFC implies the consistency of adding any of them to ZFC. So, the same argument applies to both cases.

Comment: @Zuhair No it doesn’t. It’s not provable (in ZFC) that ZFC doesn’t prove $\lnot $Con(ZFC). If it were, that would violate Godel’s theorem for ZFC+Con(ZFC).

Comment: @Zuhair also, it’s just a very well-known fact that adding Con(T) to T increases consistency strength… I give the reasoning in my previous comment but instead of arguing further I suggest you just look it up.

Comment: Ok, then. Back to the Rosser sentence. If we add it to ZFC won't that addition enable the resulting theory to prove that ZFC cannot prove it (i.e. the Rosser sentence), and this would prove Con(ZFC) in the resulting theory?!

Comment: @Zuhair No, unlike the Godel sentence, the Rosser sentence doesn’t imply it’s own unprovability. Con(ZFC) implies the Rosser sentence, but not the other way around (whereas the Godel sentence is equivalent to Con(ZFC)).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, Ah! I see. Thanks.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I was reviewing this, it appears to me that ZFC+ R does prove that R is unprovable in ZFC; not only that, it also proves that the negation of R is not provable in ZFC as well. That said then ZFC + R does prove Con(ZFC). Actually Rosser's sentence is even stronger than Godel's sentence in the sense that it offers dual unprovability by just assuming ZFC being consistent.

Comment: I think you meant it is not proved (in ZFC) that "$\sf Con(ZFC) \to (ZFC \not \vdash \neg Con(ZFC))$".

Comment: @Zuhair “it appears to you” but you don’t substantiate it. The negation of something is easier to prove unprovable, so it’s stronger? Yes, I did miss the “Con(ZFC) $\to$“ there. So in other words, ZFC + Con(ZFC) is strictly higher consistency strength than ZFC.

Comment: There's a more straighforward refutation: since (weak base theory proves) $\sf Con(T)\to Con(T+R),$ if $\sf T+R$ proved $\sf Con(T),$ it would prove $\sf Con(T+R),$ contra incompleteness (unless $\sf T+R$ and hence $\sf T$ is incosistent). But at this point I guess you just don't believe the Rosser sentence is equiconsistent, though you don't say why

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, yes I agree now that it is weaker, but I don't know how to reconcile that with the apparent opposing situation that ZFC + R does prove R, and also it proves [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick#Rosser's_theorem) and so it proves that R is not provable from ZFC, but this mean that it proves that ZFC is consistent because it proves there is a sentence that ZFC doesn't prove, namely R itself (also $\neg$R). So, why this argument is wrong.

Comment: @Zuhair Rosser’s theorem says *if ZFC is consistent*, then ZFC doesn’t prove $R$ (or $\lnot R$). ZFC does prove Rosser’s theorem but Rosser’s theorem doesn’t imply ZFC is consistent… it’s predicated on it.